# Huawei CE6851-48S6Q-HI rebooted suddenly

Tags: huawei

i have a CE6851-48S6Q-HI with the following information:

```
VRP (R) software, Version 8.180 (CE6851HI V200R005C10SPC800)

HUAWEI CE6851-48S6Q-HI uptime is 1 day, 9 hours, 41 minutes

CE6851-48S6Q-HI(Master) 1 : uptime is  1 day, 9 hours, 40 minutes

        StartupTime 2022/10/07   07:33:05+04:30

Memory    Size    : 2048 M bytes

Flash     Size    : 1024 M bytes

CE6851-48S6Q-HI version information

1. PCB    Version : CEM48S6QP04    VER B

2. MAB    Version : 1

3. Board  Type    : CE6851-48S6Q-HI

4. CPLD1  Version : 103

5. CPLD2  Version : 103

6. BIOS   Version : 433
```

yesterday my switch rebooted without any reason and when i checked "display device board reset 1" command it shows this:

```
Board 1 reset information:

-- 1. DATE:2022-10-07  TIME:07:33:05+04:30  BARCODE:2102X  RESET Num:1

--    Reason:Board register, BarCode is 2102X.

--    BootMode:NORMAL

--    BootCode:0x060100ff

-- 2. DATE:2022-10-07  TIME:07:29:18+04:30  BARCODE:21023X  RESET Num:1

--    Reason:LAN Switch parity/ecc error, and reset board.(CPU Reset)

--    BootMode:NORMAL

--    BootCode:0x80000160
```

i searched a bit and find https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1100164803 and i think it was a software issue or bug that cause this,

Do you have any idea? can i ignore this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Parity/ECC error indicates a memory error. The linked document calls it "soft" because it may be recoverable. A software issue/bug is very unlikely.

Possible causes include random glitches by background radition or power instabilities, but the most likely cause is a memory or other hardware defect, unfortunately.

The linked page recommends

> Collect logs, diagnostic information, and the output of the **display
> reset-snapshot** *time* (in diagnostic view) command, and contact
> technical support personnel

which is what you should do.

Comment: So it can be recoverable means it can be not happen again?

Comment: *It **may** be recoverable* means it *may* happen again, depending on the cause.